# How to read powershell table from file

Tags: powershell

I have this content in a file:

```
File Versions              
---- --------              
aaa  {1.0.0.123, 1.0.0.124}
bbb  {1.0.0.123, 1.0.0.124}
```

**How to read it in powershell into table, or typed array?**

I've created the file by this script:

```
$versions = $dictionary | ForEach-Object{
   $properties = @{
      File =  $dictionary.Key
      Versions = $dictionary.Value <# an array of strings #> 
   }
   New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}

$versions | Out-File "filesVersions.txt"
```

The script is not used anymore. It's just for demostration of what is in the `filesVersions.txt` file.

What I actually want is to store a key value pairs in a file, where key is FileName and Value is list of versions.

From time to time I need to read the file content, all a new row or a new version to existing row and save it back.

I wanted to use `Format-Table` output for it.

Comment: That looks like you saved `Format-Table` output to a file. Do you have control over that output. It would be easier to address that problem then to parse it back now. Or is it actually a CSV file and you could just use `Import-CSV "filesVersions.csv"`. Or is this a large file and that is why you use `ReadAllLines`?

Comment: What is `$versions`?

Comment: See my edit with a little more explanation. It does not matter what is filesVersions.csv or $dictionary since it does not exist anymore. It's just my test data, which I saved to a file and I want to read it back.

Comment: @Liero You can't (reliably) do that - how would you determine whether `{1.0.0.123, 1.0.0.124}` represents an array (of what? could be versions, IP addresses) or just the string literal `"{1.0.0.123, 1.0.0.124}"`?

As @Matt said, exporting to another format in the first place is how you'd solve this problem in the real world (eg. `Export-CliXml` or `Export-Csv` instead of formatted output to `Out-File`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I wanted to use Format-Table output for it.* Sorry but that is not the way you should be doing it. You are adding a lot of unnecessary overhead. You are looking at string parsing which *can* be unreliable and tedious.

PowerShell's power comes from objects. Using `Export-CSV` would be ideal in this situation. However you would need to do something with that array going both directions.

```
$versions = $dictionary | ForEach-Object{
   $properties = @{
      File =  $dictionary.Key
      Versions = $dictionary.Value -join "|"
   }
   New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}

$versions | Export-Csv "filesVersions.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

When you go to import the data back into PowerShell to get the objects you would need to split that field to get the array back.

```
Import-Csv "filesVersions.csv" | ForEach-Object{
    # Update the property
    $_.Versions = $_.Versions -split "|"
    # Send the updated object down the pipe
    $_
}
```

Or using a calculated property

```
Import-Csv "filesVersions.csv" | Select-Object File,@{Name="Versions";Expression={$_.Versions -split "|"}}
```

Like [Mathias says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132498/how-to-read-powershell-table-from-file/35133636#comment57986704_35132498) you could also use `Export-CLIXML` and you would not need to do the join or anything. I personally think that is for more complex output then what you are doing here.

Answer (score 1):

*"That is not the way you should be doing it"*, as @Matt wrote, is what I would like to state at first myself.
But I like to think out of the box and question *what if* there is:

- a cmdlet that would be able to convert from a **easy to read** *fixed width* table?
- a cmdlet that allows you to easy convert an embedded (object) table in your script?
- a cmdlet that can deal with little more than just strings?

In other words: couldn't it be that in some cases a fixed width `SourceTable` sometimes makes more sense than an uglyfied `cvs` or `xml` table?

### [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable)

`ConvertFrom-SourceTable` (alias  `cfst`) is capable reading most fixed width tables without any help. Unfortunately, the example in the question is probably not the best example: although, `ConvertFrom-SourceTable` is able restore (right aligned) types as e.g. integers, it is not able to restore the odd array format from the [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-6) output. Nevertheless, you can use the native [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) to resolve this part of the issue:

```
ConvertFrom-SourceTable '
    File Versions
    ---- --------
    aaa  {1.0.0.123, 1.0.0.124}
    bbb  {1.0.0.123, 1.0.0.124}
' | 
Select-Object File, @{n='Versions'; e={$_.Versions.TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}') -Split '\s*,\s*'}}
```

<sub>For the latest version of `ConvertFrom-SourceTable`, see the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) or [GitHub](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable)</sub>

Comment: Is a bit odd how in powershell is so easy to save files, and is rather convoluted to read them back. I was saving pscustomobjects, and couldn't figure out how to read the table back. ConvertFrom-SourceTable is the most straight forward solution here. +1